# Most efficient SQL to exclude rows where nvarchar column contains specific words

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have an editable list of words that I want to keep adding to, and I want to query and page results from a Table containing a list of news items, but exclude anywhere the news `Title` contains the words.

Currently, my exclude list includes 70+ words, but this could expand a little more.

Table structure example

```
Id (int), Title (nvarchar), Date (Date), Content (nvarchar)
```

I'm currently using Entity Framework, but the query it generates is so slow, I'm looking to see if there is a manual SQL way to do this.

I'm building up the query in EF Core by looping the list of words like so (`TitleUpper` is just `Title` saved in uppercase)

```
foreach (var keyword in keywords)
{
    var upperKeyword = keyword.Text.ToUpper();
    queryable = queryable.Where(x =>
        !x.TitleUpper.Contains(upperKeyword));
}
```

I have a number of other `Where` statements and I'm also paging too, but it's this part that is causing it to slow drastically. I have an index on the `Title` & `TitleUpper` columns.

Any help appreciated

Comment: When you use contains like that you have rendered it impossible to use any indexes. It means the query engine has to look at the text for every single row to see if the word is in there. Think of a phone book. Now think about finding all the entries that begin with the letter "C". Easy to find right? Now think about finding all entries that contain the letter "C". You know have to look at every single entry in the entire phone book. That is what your query is doing.

Comment: If you really need to do this kind of searching you will probably want to look into [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Have you tried referencing `SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions` in your project so that you can make use of SQL Server's built-in [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.contains) and [FreeText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext) functions? Also, if your database is not using a case sensitive collation then you don't need to uppercase your search term and search column for comparison.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, same performance issues.